# Review my logical model for gaps

Tags: database-design

We need to centralize our ability to manage the various schedules that our banking centers keep since it is a manual nightmare right now.    Do you see any obvious gaps in this?

[image: Service Location Schedule - Logical Model]

A schedule is defined by a set of Days of the Week, open times and close times.
A logical record may look like this:

```
service_location    service_location_type  day_of_week  open_time  close_time
Main Street Branch  Lobby                  Monday       8am        5pm
Main Street Branch  Lobby                  Tuesday      8am        5pm
Main Street Branch  Lobby                  Wednesday    8am        12pm
```

I want to be able to reuse Schedules but am worried something here is a a bit off.

Comment: To those who wondered: the image can bee seen [at normal size](http://i.stack.imgur.com/R9htW.jpg) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your plan is to re-use schedules I would recommend a change in your thinking as follows:

a) Each service location can have one or more schedules - called location schedules (basically this is an association between a location, a predefined schedule and other data)

b) Each location schedule can have a priority (which allows you to create a custom schedule that overrides the default schedule)

c) Each location schedule has a start date and an end date when its active - which allows you to define a custom schedule which is active for only a specific period of time

d) A schedule has a name and description

e) A schedule has one or more schedule details - day of week, opening time, closing time

I have included an explanatory data model (MySQL)

[image: Solution Data Model]

Comment: I like that much better.  Much cleaner and will support  use cases with less fuss.